# need replace alias value of predefined variables in azure devops pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have enabled pipeline resource triggers between two pipelines. would like to replace alias value dynamically with triggering pipeline resource. below is the pipeline code

```
  resources:        
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeline1
    project: onecom
    source: pipeline1-api
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - develop    
      - feat/*
  - pipeline: pipeline2
    project: onecom
    source: pipeline2-api 
    trigger:
      branches:
      - develop
      - feat
  variables:
  - name: apiname
    value:  $(resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineName)
  - name: dockertag
    value: $(resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceCommit)
  - name: runname
    value: $(resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runName)

stages:
- stage: ScanImage

  jobs:
  - job: ScanImage

    pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

    steps:
    - script: echo $(apiname)
    - script: echo $(runname)
```

I would like to replace **Alias** value in  $(resources.pipeline..pipelineName)  with value **pipeline1** if build comes from **source: pipeline1-api** and with **pipeline2** if build comes from source: **pipeline2-api** dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to replace Alias value in $(resources.pipeline..pipelineName) with value pipeline1 if build comes from source: pipeline1-api and with pipeline2 if build comes from source: pipeline2-api dynamically.

Since the value of nested variables (like `$(resources.pipeline.$(alias).pipelineName))` are not yet supported in the build/release pipelines. So we could not use it in the variable directly:

```
  variables:
  - name: apiname
    value:  $(resources.pipeline.$(alias).pipelineName)
```

To resolve this issue, we need add a inline powershell to set the variable `resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineName` based on the value of the `$(resources.triggeringAlias)`:

```
variables:
  - name: alias
    value: $(resources.triggeringAlias)


    - task: InlinePowershell@1
      inputs:
        script: |
          if ("$(alias)" -eq "PipelineA")
          {
            Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(resources.pipeline.PipelineA.sourceCommit) | cut -c -7")
          }
          elseif ("$(alias)" -eq "PipelineB")
          {
            Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(resources.pipeline.PipelineB.sourceCommit) | cut -c -7")
          }
```

**Update:**

> could you please help me same config in bash as we are using these
> task in linux machines

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Inline Powershell'
  inputs:
    TargetType: inline
    Script: |
      if ("$(alias)" -eq "PipelineA")
      {
        Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(resources.pipeline.PipelineA.sourceCommit) | cut -c -7")
      }
      elseif ("$(alias)" -eq "PipelineB")
      {
        Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(resources.pipeline.PipelineB.sourceCommit) | cut -c -7")
      }
    pwsh: true
```

Comment: Ok, do we need to do this in each and every stage of deployment ? or is it possible to set this at globally so they are available across all stage of deployment.

also any another simple way of doing this as i would be having almost 40 to 50 pipelines triggering the same pipeline for deployment.

Comment: @pranathi, Yes, you have to add this in each and every stage of deployment, but you could create a task group for this task, then just need add this task group  in each and every stage of deployment without configure each powershell task.

Comment: i think in multistage pipeline task group does not work right

Comment: @pranathi, oh, This is my fault. I thought of this idea subconsciously without considering the limitations of YAML. You are right, I'm afraid we have to add this in each and every stage of deployment now.

Comment: Thanks.  i would like to have first 7 character of commit hash id for docket tag.
does it work if i write like below
Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]'$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1-api.sourceCommit) | cut -c -7' ")

Comment: @pranathi, It should be work. I test it on my side, and I have updated the scripts, please check it. **Change** `$alias` to `"$(alias)"`. and **remove the single quotes** for `'$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1-api.sourceCommit) | cut -c -7' `

Comment: Ok, thanks, could you please help me same config in bash as we are using these task in linux machines

Comment: @pranathi, Powershell task should works on the linux machines, we just need give a little change in the scripts, you could check my updated answer, I test it on linux machines, and it works fine. Check the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
  variables:
  - name: alias
    value: $(resources.triggeringAlias)
```

then you can try replace it as below

$(resources.pipeline.$(alias).pipelineName)

Comment: thanks i get alias name but when i try to replace it  in $(resources.pipeline.$(alias).pipelineName) it throws following error
resources.pipeline.aliasvalue.pipelineName : command not found